# How do I convert my byte data to integer using python?

Tags: python, integer, byte

I have a byte data is like:  `b'\xc4\x03\x00\x00\xe2\xecqv\x01'`.
How do I convert  this to integer like index by index.

Comment: It depends on how you want to interpret that as integers. You can take each byte and convert it to integer, or each bit, or each 16-bit word or interpret the whole data as one integer, or anything else. In the end it sums up to question: how did you get that binary data in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object is basically already a (immutable) sequence of integers.

```
b = b'\xc4\x03\x00\x00\xe2\xecqv\x01'
b[0] # 196
lst = list(b)
#  [196, 3, 0, 0, 226, 236, 113, 118, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access throug indexes:

```
>>> b = b'\xc4\x03\x00\x00\xe2\xecqv\x01'
>>> b[0]
196

>>> for i in b:
...     print(i)
... 
196
3
0
0
226
236
113
118
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python v.3, you can use the int_from_bytes() function:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\xc4\x03\x00\x00\xe2\xecqv\x01', byteorder='big')
```